# Why does my debugger show extra characters in character array?

Tags: arrays, c, debugging, codeblocks, c-strings

Notice the input string value shown:

[image: debugger screenshot]

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 50
int main()
{
    printf("\nEnter string:");
    char input[MAX];
    gets(input);
    puts(input);
    return 0;
}
```

I entered "(A+B)*C" as input. But why does the debugger show extra characters?

Shouldn't it be just \0 at the end?

Comment: You have an array of size 50 - those extra characters are displayed by your debugger

Comment: automatic variables will have random data in the uninitialized portion.  Try clearing with `memset(input,0,MAX)` before calling gets (which is deprecated, btw).

Comment: @stark that worked!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: I am shocked that your C compiler let you use `gets()`. I get about 7 lines of warning messages when I try it.

Comment: @ZanLynx I am using Codeblocks IDE along with mingw32 compiler and it didnt show even a single warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `fgets()` instead of `gets()` because `gets()` can be dangerous (In order to use `gets()` safely, you have to know exactly how many characters you will be reading, so that you can make your buffer large enough). `fgets()` also takes the `'\n'` char at the end, in order to prevent this you can write the following line: `input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';`

As for your question @Fiddling Bits already provided correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

A string in C is terminated by the `NUL` character: `'\0'`.  You can ignore all characters after this in your array, `input`, as they are uninitialized/garbage.

You can, though it's unnecessary in your case, initialize your array before using it:

```
char input[MAX] = {'\0'};
```

This way you'll see all `'\0'`s after `"(A+B)*C"`.

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Garbage data` that is stored on the address that your buffer got, and was not used. You can simply make it go away by adding a null terminator '\n' .